# select * from where table=Today's Date in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I have a query where I need to use the today's date in the where clause.

The original query is:

```
 select * 
 from hist 
 where checkdt = '8/18/2017' 
   and status = 'R' 
   and PSPAY is not null
```

But I need to replace the date with a get date function.

```
 select * 
 from hist 
 where checkdt = Today's Date 
   and status = 'R' 
   and PSPAY is not null
```

I have used the `GetDate()` and `curdate()` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can u tell what is the data type of checkdt?

Comment: @VidiyaPrasanth it's datetime

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
select h.*
from hist h
where checkdt = cast(getdate() as date) and
      status = 'R' and
      PSPAY is not null;
```

In SQL Server, the `cast()` can still make use of an index, so this is the best approach.